# FD_ISSET keeps reading though there's no data in c

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having issues with listening on multiple sockets. I have a function which listens on a bunch of sockets but when I test and only send data on 1 of the sockets; The FD_ISSET method keeps returning true for every socket and no data gets returned in the buffer for the sockets I didn't send data too (because there is none). I am using each socket for both send and receive.
What am i doing wrong ?

EDIT: Whats happening is the printf statement is printing multiple times when it should only be printing once as I've only sent data on 1 socket. I've added in testing for the return value of read()>0 and it still no joy.

```
void receive(struct nodeData *nd, struct sockInfo *si){
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 1000;

    // ----Wait in select until file descriptors change----
    int y = select(si->maxFD, &si->fd_read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    printf("ID: %d  Y %d\n", nd->id, y);
    if (y <= 0)
        return;
    for (int i=0; i < nd->netTopo->n; i++) {
        /* ----Was it child i---- */
        if (FD_ISSET(si->mastFD[i], &si->fd_read_set)) {
            read(si->mastFD[i], buffer, MAXBUF);
            printf("%d %d %d \n",buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2]); //  For Testing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you resetting `fd_read_set` each time you call `select()`? You need to, since `select()` alters it, but you did not show the code that is preparing `fd_read`set`.

Comment: No I'm not resetting the read set each time. I ZERO it once then SET it. Where would I reset the FD_SET each time ?

Comment: I resetting and still no joy

Comment: Please update your question to show your latest code. You must zero+set the `fd_set` every time your call `select()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the return value of `read`. EOF is a readable condition (causing `select` to report the file descriptor as readable, i.e. `FD_ISSET` to return true) which you need to detect via `read` returning 0. After EOF you probably want to close the file descriptor and remove it from the set to `select` on.

Comment: Thanks for replying. These listen sockets are persistent sockets and I need to send on them shortly after. So still close them and remove them from the set?

Comment: Yes. When `select()` reports a socket is readable and then `read()` returns 0 from that socket, it means the peer has closed the connection on its end, so you need to close that socket on your end and stop using it.